# What if a helium-filled ball was thrown towards the earth?

Tags: planets, physics, space

Suppose some alien hovering 100's of miles above the earth has constructed a big ball/sphere and filled it with helium, and decides to throw that ball towards the earth.

Would the air-helium density difference keep the ball up, floating above the earth like an (almost) stationary satellite? If so, what altitude would it hover at? If not, what would happen exactly?

(Suppose the earth is stationary, so no complex orbital mechanics need to be involved)

Comment: This depends entirely on the weight of the container - please provide us with a description of the container - size, weight and volume of helium allowed

Comment: @bendl Suppose the ball was positively-buoyant, meaning if launched from sea level, its lift force would be bigger than its gravitational force.

Comment: The answer still depends on the size and weight - a huge positively buoyant sphere could have too much momentum to stop in time. Also the buoyancy of the sphere will affect where in the atmosphere it will come to rest, if it is indeed possible for it to float

Comment: How is this about creating fictional world, exactly?

Comment: If the ball is thrown towards Earth with typical orbital speed, the container will likely burn before reaching neutral buoyancy level and helium will be released to atmosphere.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep into account the average density of the ball (shell and helium inside it) and compare it to the density of the atmosphere at the height where the ball is.

If the ball's density is higher than the atmospheric density at sea level, the ball will fall due to gravity and will splat on the surface.

If the ball's density is lower, it will sink until the density of the atmosphere being crossed becomes higher. At that point the sphere will be slowed down by buoyancy forces and drag. If the height is not sufficient the sphere will splat again, else it will slow down until stopping and then rising back.

In this last case the motion will be oscillatory with progressively less amplitude until drag dissipates all the kinetic energy.

Without information on the size and composition of your sphere we cannot give more details.

Comment: Don't forget compression heating and issues with initial momentum. Hundreds of miles can be pretty far above the "edge" of atmosphere.